# Changing background color with fading animation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fade

I'm completely new to jQuery and I'm stuck on how to make my fixed header change its background color with fading animation while scrolling. I want it to be completely transparent ( no background color ) once reaching something like 50px when scrolling

```css
.Header_Fix{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CLL-FST</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <!--JQUERY-->
        
        <script type = "text/javascript" 
         src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /* Fading Header Here */
        
        </script>
        
    </head>
    
    <div class="Header_Fix">
            <a href=""><img src="img/CLL_Logo.jpg" id="CLL_Logo"></a>
            <div class="Header_Buttons">
                <a href="" class="Header_Button">CLL</a>
                <a href="" class="Header_Button">Members</a>
                <a href="" class="Header_Button">About Us</a>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: See how you can modify this to suit your need:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675604/changing-background-color-of-div-on-scroll

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).scroll(function(){
 var scrollPosition =  $(this).scrollTop();
 if(scrollPosition > 50){
    $('.Header_Fix').fadeIn('slow').css('background-color','#ff0000');
 }
 else{
  $('.Header_Fix').css('background-color','transparent');
 }

});
```

```css
.Header_Fix{
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
    <div class="Header_Fix">
            <a href=""><img src="img/CLL_Logo.jpg" id="CLL_Logo"></a>
            <div class="Header_Buttons">
                <a href="" class="Header_Button">CLL</a>
                <a href="" class="Header_Button">Members</a>
                <a href="" class="Header_Button">About Us</a>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div >
    Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document. To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
Themes and styles also help keep your document coordinated. When you click Design and choose a new Theme, the pictures, charts, and SmartArt graphics change to match your new theme. When you apply styles, your headings change to match the new theme. Save time in Word with new buttons that show up where you need them. To change the way a picture fits in your document, click it and a button for layout options appears next to it. When you work on a table, click where you want to add a row or a column, and then click the plus sign.
Reading is easier, too, in the new Reading view. You can collapse parts of the document and focus on the text you want. If you need to stop reading before you reach the end, Word remembers where you left off - even on another device. Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.
To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries. Themes and styles also help keep your document coordinated. When you click Design and choose a new Theme, the pictures, charts, and SmartArt graphics change to match your new theme. When you apply styles, your headings change to match the new theme.
Save time in Word with new buttons that show up where you need them. To change the way a picture fits in your document, click it and a button for layout options appears next to it. When you work on a table, click where you want to add a row or a column, and then click the plus sign. Reading is easier, too, in the new Reading view. You can collapse parts of the document and focus on the text you want. If you need to stop reading before you reach the end, Word remembers where you left off - even on another device.
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document. To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.

    </div>
    
      <div>
    Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document. To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.
Themes and styles also help keep your document coordinated. When you click Design and choose a new Theme, the pictures, charts, and SmartArt graphics change to match your new theme. When you apply styles, your headings change to match the new theme. Save time in Word with new buttons that show up where you need them. To change the way a picture fits in your document, click it and a button for layout options appears next to it. When you work on a table, click where you want to add a row or a column, and then click the plus sign.
Reading is easier, too, in the new Reading view. You can collapse parts of the document and focus on the text you want. If you need to stop reading before you reach the end, Word remembers where you left off - even on another device. Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document.
To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries. Themes and styles also help keep your document coordinated. When you click Design and choose a new Theme, the pictures, charts, and SmartArt graphics change to match your new theme. When you apply styles, your headings change to match the new theme.
Save time in Word with new buttons that show up where you need them. To change the way a picture fits in your document, click it and a button for layout options appears next to it. When you work on a table, click where you want to add a row or a column, and then click the plus sign. Reading is easier, too, in the new Reading view. You can collapse parts of the document and focus on the text you want. If you need to stop reading before you reach the end, Word remembers where you left off - even on another device.
Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point. When you click Online Video, you can paste in the embed code for the video you want to add. You can also type a keyword to search online for the video that best fits your document. To make your document look professionally produced, Word provides header, footer, cover page, and text box designs that complement each other. For example, you can add a matching cover page, header, and sidebar. Click Insert and then choose the elements you want from the different galleries.

    </div>
```